# Replace "\\" with "\" in an imported data.frame in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have next csv file:

```
x,y,label
2,3,A
3,4,C\n2
4,5,B
```

"\n" in the csv file means a second line. But, when I import this file, R replace "\n" with "\\n". And when use `ggplot`, generates a graph without a second line:

```r
library(ggplot2)
data <- read.csv("text.txt")
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label))
```

[image]

I tried to use `data$label <- gsub("\\\\", "\\", data$label)` but replace "C\n2" to "Cn2".

I tried to use `cat` inside to geom_text: `label = cat(label)`. But return error.

I can modified manually with `data$label[2] <- "C\n2"`:

```r
data$label[2] <- "C\n2"
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label))
```

[image]

but it requires automating for a larger amount of data.

How can I keep "\n"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We could replace the `\` with `sub`

```
data$label <- sub("\\\\n", "\n", data$label)
```

Now, using the OP's code for `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
   geom_text(aes(label = label))
```

[image]

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(x = 2:4, y = 3:5, label = c("A", "C\\n2", 
 "B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```